# Backup Buddy Questions

Tags: plugins, backup

I have two hosting accounts.

1. Account #1) My personal hosting account
2. Account #2) My reseller hosting account

I am hosting a friend/client on my personal account as an `Add On` domain. I just purchased a reseller account and want to move this friend to their own cpanel as an account on my reseller. I've created the new account for them, using the domain name from the WordPress they are hosting on my personal hosting account...

I've just purchased BackUp Buddy but have limited faith in the software.

I have just created a BackUp Buddy of the site I am trying to save. If I don't remove the `Add On` domain from my personal hosting account the site won't propagate on the new account because it'll link back somehow. I know this because I tried this with an empty site I had. The problem is, when I **remove** an `Add On` domain it deletes ALL the folders. So I would lose the entire site.

Here is my thoughts on the process I need to do.

1. Create BackUp Buddy Backup file [done]
2. Download importbuddy.php file [done]
3. FTP Copy the entire Folder structure of the WordPress install as extra measure [done]
4. Remove `Add On` domain [*scared, not done yet*]
5. Change Namerservers to point to new account on my reseller [to do]
6. Run Importbuddy.php [to do]
7. Delete MySQL DB & DBUser on personal account [to do]

Then... if there is a problem... I **BELIEVE** I can:

1. Change Nameservers back.
2. Upload copy of files structure.

And the site is back...

Am I correct? I'm very concerned that something irreversible is going to happen to this site.

Comment: "If I don't remove the Add On domain from my personal hosting account the site won't transfer" I don't see how this connects to BackupBuddy mechanics? Also this seems very specific to plugin and probably best asked at their support forum.

Comment: Their support forum isn't answering. They moved my question to an obscure forum too, so I'm not sure it's even getting seen. So I am not considering them to be much of a help.

Also, the reason I am asking here is simply to find out if my reasoning on my precaution... would that work if things went awry?